# RSpec matcher which expects to raise an instance of error class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have test:

`expect { subject }.to raise_error(AngellistApi::Error)`

and it fails with this error message:

`expected AngellistApi::Error, got #<AngellistApi::Error: message> with backtrace:`

So I was expecting Class but received instance of it.

How to expect instance of a class to make this test pass?

Comment: should you be changing your test to make it pass, or changing your code to make it pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `kind_of` which checks if parameter is an instance of a given class.

`expect { subject }.to raise_error(kind_of(error.class))`

it takes class name as the argument so remember to call `.class` on your instance